# How to find the Security Patch updates in Android

Tags: android, android-source

I am seeing [this security patch](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2018-06-01) has been applied to only 8.1 code. Other source code versions (e.g. 6.0, 7.0) have not been updated as claimed below:

[image]

The [Android Source website](http://android.googlesource.com/) was referenced for the patch changes. However I could only find the patch changes for the 8.1 latest version of Android and not other versions. Are there any separate commit branches for Android 6.0, etc? Where can I find the code with the updated patch as mentioned in the Android Bulletin about the security updates?

Answer (score 0):

**android-6.0.1_r81** is the latest branch for marshmallow and this security patch **cve-2018-9341** is not applied in this branch. So you need to apply the patch to  libmpeg2 manually